# How to check if my listview adapter is filterd by my editext text or not?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a editext for search in a list view. I want to check if listview adapter is filtered by any text or not. Here is my code:

```
    Button search=(Button)findViewByld(R.id.bsearch);
    search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
       {
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(inputSearch.getText().toString()); 

    //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    if(adapter was filtered by a text)
    {
       // Do some things
    } 

    }}); 


   }
}
```

Hope to get my purpose. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[`Filter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Filter) has a overridden method with `Filter.FilterListener` which you can use .

```
search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(inputSearch.getText().toString(),new Filter.FilterListener(){
                @Override
                public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                    if (count == 0){
                        // List empty
                    } else {
                        // List has data
                    }
                }
            });
        }});
```